# Codeigniter restful simple api take too much time

Tags: php, mysql, api, codeigniter, postman

I am creating simple restful api using CodeIgniter with mysql database.Api is very simple just one simple query fetching multiple records from database.My mysql query taking 0.0054 but in postman time section it is showing 1693ms i.t more than 1 second.But i want to optimize my api and i want to know why it take more than 1 second.Also when first time when i call my api it take time more than 1500ms but second time if i call after few second it take 600-900 ms Why?

I tried putting index on my database table also.Below is my query.

`SELECT Id,Name,Freq,userid FROM categories WHERE isactive = 1 AND (userid =0 or userid = 100)`

Below is my api code

`public function categorieslist_post(){

```
    $apiKeys = $this->post('apiKeys');
    if($this->config->item('custom_token') == $apiKeys){
        $UserId = trim($this->post('userid')) ? trim($this->post('userid')) : '';   
        if($userid != ''){
            $Categories = $this->test_model->getCategoriesList($userid);
            $this->response([
                'Categories' => $Categories,
                'Error' => "",
                'Status' => True
                    ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
                    
        }else{
            $this->response([
            'Categories' => array(),
            'Error' => "userid are required!",
            'Status' => FALSE
                ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        }
     
    }else{
        $this->response([
            'Categories' => array(),
            'Error' => "Invalid APIKey",
            'Status' => FALSE
                ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
}`
```

One more thing i have Aws window server with 1 GB of RAM is this a issue ?Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add this index to `categories`:

```
INDEX(isactive, userid)
```

1GB of RAM is tiny these days.  (Still, it is adequate for small apps.)  What is the value here:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
```

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` controls the size of the main cache.

- Too small:  Lots of I/O needed for queries.
- Just right:  Queries are performed entirely in RAM, hence fast.
- Too big:  Swapping slows down MySQL severely due to a different type of I/O.

For 1GB of RAM:

- 16M is "too small"; many queries will run slowly.
- 100M might be "just right".
- Bigger would lead to swapping, hence "very slow".

Comment: thanks for reply above query return 16777216 this number.

Comment: @ArjunChoudhary - 16M is terribly low; 100M might be better.

Comment: is this a reason why my api are taking more time?

Comment: My Api working very fast on my local PC using localhost. Response time is very low but on server it's very high in some api it reached at 2-3 seconds.

Comment: @ArjunChoudhary - The "server" is set to 16M?  And it is busier than the "local PC"?  In that case, blocks are being bumped out of cache more often.  Hence slower.

Comment: i have increased RAM from 1 GB to GB but still response time is not decreased although it is taking more time than previous one.

Comment: @ArjunChoudhary - Did you increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` after increasing RAM?